# When is this JSON structure getting converted to all strings?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, jsonp

I am sending a JSON structure to my node/express server and saving the object into a database. The problem is that I send JSON with integers and booleans but everything gets saved as strings.

Here is my node/express code:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.enable("jsonp callback");
app.use(express.bodyParser());

// allow cross origin scripting to get data from devices directly
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
});

app.post('/departures', function(req, res) {

/* I started using this to convert back to integers - but need to solve the problem
    for (var i in req.body.data) {
      req.body.data[i].siteid = parseInt(req.body.data[i].siteid);
    }
*/
    console.log('saving data '+JSON.stringify(req.body.data));
    positionProvider.save(req.body.data, function(){
      res.json({status:'success'});
    })
});
```

Here is how I am POSTing with jquery:

```
    var data = [{"siteid":123}];

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: serverUrl + '/departures',
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            alert('saved departure data '+JSON.stringify(data))
        },
        error: function(err) {
            console.log('error posting to server...');
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

The jquery side reports that it sent {"siteid":123} but the node side reports that it received {"siteid":"123"}.

Where is the integer getting converted to a string?

Comment: What database are you using?  What does your model object look like?

Comment: I am using mongodb so it happily stores whatever I hand it.

Comment: That's what I use on a normal basis as well.  Do you use mongoose models to set the data structure?

Comment: I'm new to mongo - no data models yet. That sounds like a solution but I'm hoping someone has an answer as to why my types are getting converted during the POST.

Comment: What does your data look like in Mongo?  Is it a string inside Mongo?

Comment: The collection is JSON documents - it stores whatever JSON I send in. find({siteid:123}) and find({siteid:"123"}) each give different but appropriate results.

Comment: Ok. I was looking for if it was storing the appropriate data as a string or as an integer.  I think you are getting the strings when you JSON.Stringify(req.body.data)

Comment: I thought that too, but the client side log message prints the array correctly. The data that gets stored is stored as strings, as demonstrated by the separate find() results mentioned above.

Comment: are you inserting site id and the number into one field?

Comment: var data is an array containing one object with key siteid and value 123.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your data is converted to a string as a product of sending it from client to server. Remember, the client and server are not actually communicating in JSON, they are communicating in text or binary data. The server (Express?) implicitly interprets the data sent as a string, which is converted to JSON if you include the `content-type: application/json` request header. You'll need explicitly to type check and convert on the server if you want the data to persist in a specific format.

TLDR (comments); don't rely on the client to send valid data. Clean it before you save it to the database.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm getting around this at the moment by stringifying on the client and parsing on the server. Integers and booleans survive.

Comment: Actually, I suspect that express.bodyParser() is losing the types. Doesn't jquery just stringify() the data and send it in the body? When I do this manually and parse() on the server, my integers and booleans, etc. keep their types.

Comment: That's fine, just be aware that you're going to run into challenges and hard-to-find bugs if you perform logic with or on that data after restoring it from a persisted state!

Comment: I don't know if jQuery simply calls `JSON.stringify()` or not. Regardless, I highly recommend type-checking or casting before you persist data to prevent inconsistencies in data formatting from ruining your day. You're already seeing mixed results between jQuery and your own work.

Comment: Agreed - I should use a data model (Mongoose?) Note that the mixed results are both using jquery - the difference is whether I send bodyParser an object or send it a string and parse myself.

Comment: I've never used Mongoose, but it's very popular, and likely a faster solution than writing your own. If your project is small, though, writing your own might be fun.

Comment: To be clear, the problem you are warning about is that at some point,  a client is likely to send a bad object, so I need to validate the object before I database it. Correct? So, for a small situation, could this just be a function that ensures types before persisting the object?

Answer (score 11):

I ran into same problem. jQuery $.post and $.ajax converts integers into strings when stringifying JSON. You can verify it by looking at the data on the server side. Server receives something like { "age": "3" }, while you really want { "age": 3 }.

The solution that works is to avoid giving jQuery pure objects, but give it a string instead:

`$.ajax({
    type:'POST', 
    url: '/api/...', 
    data: JSON.stringify(data), 
    contentType: 'application/json'
})`

Comment: Adding the above into the header worked for me. Then server side(Express) I just ```bodyParser.json()```  as middleware to parse the JSON and then ```req.body.propName``` and was able to get the JSON with the correct format.

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json())`