# How to post an object to API route using express without changing integers to strings

Tags: javascript, express

Currenty trying to post an object with an array of integers without success. It currently changes to string.

```
</body>

</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").on("click", function() {

   // Here we grab the form elements
   var newFriend = {
      "name": $('#name').val().trim(),
      "photo": $('#photoUrl').val().trim(),
      "scores": []
   };

   for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

      newFriend.scores.push(parseInt($('#Select' + (i + 1)).val()))

   }

   console.log(newFriend);

   var currentURL = window.location.origin;

   $.post(currentURL + "/api/friends", newFriend, {

   });

   return false;

});
</script>
```

it posts in my api as:

```
[{"name":"john","photo":"doe","scores":["2","4","5","3","1","3","1","1","5","1"]}]
```

need it to be :

```
[
    {
  "name":"Ahmed",
  "photo":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_400_400/p/6/005/064/1bd/3435aa3.jpg",
  "scores":[
     5,
     1,
     4,
     4,
     5,
     1,
     2,
     5,
     4,
     1
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, but when you receive the data to your server you can use JSON.parse() function to have what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
Because a communication between client and a server always happens with text or binary data

Refer: [When is this JSON structure getting converted to all strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15468640/when-is-this-json-structure-getting-converted-to-all-strings)

Comment: Thanks so Much!!! That makes sense, Ive tried everything and I couldn't get a straight answer from anyone.