# jsGrid issue with insertItem

Tags: jquery, json, http, grid, jsgrid

I have jsGrid working for the full CRUD operations, but when I add a new record, the post method is somehow converting all my fields to strings before transport to my API.  My API receives all the fields as strings whether they are string, number, or bool.

Here is my insertItem function:

```
           console.log( "data before post: " + JSON.stringify(item) );
           insertItem: function (item) {
                var d = $.Deferred();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://myserver...",
                    data: item,
                    dataType: "json",
                }).done(function (response) {
                    console.log( "done: " + JSON.stringify(response) );
                    d.resolve(response);
                }).fail(function( msg ) {
                console.log( "fail" + msg );
                d.reject();
            });
        }
```

If I console.log the item object before $.ajax it shows numeric fields properly.  For example:

```
data before post: {"question":"My Question","value":45,"timeout":10, "isActive":true }
```

But in the done function console.log, the json looks as follows and this is also exactly how it is being received on the server:

```
done: {"question":"My Question","value":"45","timeout":"10", "isActive":"true"}
```

If I use postman and post the proper json object, everything is fine and the data types are as they should be, so my API is not at fault.  The api response also returns the json object as it received it.

Somehow jsgrid is converting all properties values to strings before posting to my API.  This is really annoying.

**Update:**
Even if I try replacing data:item with:

```
data: {"question":"myquestio77", "value": 77}
```

The 77 is still received by my API as "77".

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer on here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34628133/679439

Basically, you have to stringify the data before you send it and of course add the contenttype which I was missing.  You must do both.

```
data: JSON.stringify(data), 
contentType: 'application/json'
```